# DataGridView with unbound DataTable grid not showing updated data until minimized and restored

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, .net-4.0

It's a simple, bare-bones C# app (as far as the Form Controls are concerned).  The DataGridView is bound to manually-populated DataTable (including column headers).  There's a menu item that begins the event-driven data acquisition process.  As the data is added to the DataTable, the Console shows each row. One row has been added with dummy data, to verify DataTable data formats (this row will eventually be removed).

When the app is launched, and the data acquisition started, the DataView does not show any changes, only the dummy row is shown.  The Console output tells me that the data is being process, and shows no errors, including overzealously trapped error messages.

Form.Refresh, DataGridView.Refresh, and DataGridView.RefreshEdit have been attempted, but appear to have no effect.

However... When the app is minimized and restored, data changes appear, and updates are shown as they are added; in other words, it "behaves".  Once minimized and restored, it continues to operate as expected, for as long as the app runs.

Any ideas, short of minimizing and restoring the app on the first activation?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using, and which version of Windows?

Comment: Found it.  After returning from vacation today with a clear head, it appears that, somehow, the event-handler is executing in another thread, which explains the trappable error when attempting to execute the `DataGridView.Refresh` method.  Hmm.

Setting the `Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false` during initialization allows the `DataGridView.Refresh` method to execute properly.  Evidently, minimizing and restoring invokes refreshing on all threads.  Nice for the back-of-the-head information pile.

Admins, you may consider this case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm brand new to StackOverflow, just noticed the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom.  See my previous comment for details.

In a nutshell, the DataGridView refreshes (properly) when running in the same thread as the invoking object.  If you're getting an error about thread access violations, then read above.